# IllegalAccessError when using DynamoDBMapper to encrypt data in EMR

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I followed this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb-encryption-client/latest/devguide/java-examples.html and setup encryption client and mapper to encrypt an items and batchsave into Table but it is not working and throwing errors as given below

stack Trace details:

ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingsRegistry from class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AttributeEncryptor at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AttributeEncryptor.getModelClassMetadata(AttributeEncryptor.java:156) at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AttributeEncryptor.transform(AttributeEncryptor.java:65) at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.transformAttributes(DynamoDBMapper.java:2180) at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.batchWrite(DynamoDBMapper.java:1229) at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.batchSave(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:193) at com.amazon.payrolldatalakeemr.awsoperations.DDBOperations$.batchSaveInDDB(DDBOperations.scala:40)

Config details:

```
        AWSJavaSDKExternalRelease = 1.11.x;
        # Spark dependencies
        Spark-core = 2.2.1;
        Spark-sql = 2.2.1;
        DaxJavaClient = 1.0;
        ANTLR-Runtime = 3.5.x;
        DynamoDbGrammar = 1.0;

        Lombok = 1.16.x;
        LombokUtils = 1.1;
        Maven-com-amazonaws_aws-dynamodb-encryption-java = 1.x;
```

Mapper code:

```
      def getDynamoDBMapper(region: String): DynamoDBMapper = {
val cmkArn = "*****************************"
val kms: AWSKMS = AWSKMSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).build()
val cmp: DirectKmsMaterialProvider = new DirectKmsMaterialProvider(kms, cmkArn)
val encryptor: DynamoDBEncryptor = DynamoDBEncryptor.getInstance(cmp)
val mapperConfig: DynamoDBMapperConfig = DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder.withSaveBehavior(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.CLOBBER).build

new DynamoDBMapper(ddclient, mapperConfig, new AttributeEncryptor(encryptor))
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after adding spark property:
--conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true